# Jenkins Workspace build and multiple Branch

Tags: git, jenkins

I currently take care of the establishment of an integration platform continues in my business.
I have several(3) GIT branches for my solution.
Today Jenkins detects Push on each of my branches and generates a compilation in
C: \ Program Files ( x86) \ Jenkins \ jobs \ PROJECT \ workspace

I wish a Workdir ( workspace ) different depending on the branch, is this possible ?
Exemple : 
C: \ Program Files ( x86) \ Jenkins \ jobs \ PROJECT \ workspace\BranchA
C: \ Program Files ( x86) \ Jenkins \ jobs \ PROJECT \ workspace\BranchC
C: \ Program Files ( x86) \ Jenkins \ jobs \ PROJECT \ workspace\BranchB

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you create a separate job for each branch, each monitoring and building it's own branch. Then they will be in separate folders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is possible.
There is an option of 'Multiple SCMs' where you can select multiple branches

[image]

and you need to set from  Additional Behaviours to "checkout to a specific directory" [image]

and in Jenkins 2.0

```
    dir ('branch-a') {
git branch: 'branch-a', changelog: false, credentialsId: 'a57f5020', poll: false, url: 'https://github.com/pratik141/python'
}

dir ('branch-b') {
git branch: 'branch-b', changelog: false, credentialsId: 'a57f5020', poll: false, url: 'https://github.com/pratik141/python'
}
```